# Manually code UI Object(GUI) in objective-c or c++, not by drag-n-drop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, user-interface

I can code well in web language ( HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP ) , i know that i use HTML and CSS to make the graphical user interface like ( form, radio, button, drop-down-selection)

In Xcode4 all the User Interface Object/Element are basically drag-n-drop, why i cannot code it ? Code it like CSS, give the position or size manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can code everything that you can do with interface builder. for example drag and drop of a button would be

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:somebuttonType];
```

then manually position it with

```
button.frame = cgrect(xpos,ypos,width,height);
```

and add it to the view u want to have it

```
[self addsubview: button];
```

all gui elements can be done in code . have a read of apples docs to check them out

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

edit: ah sorry i misunderstood. your heading says in objective-c or c++. you could always check out http://librocket.com/ . it appears to have some css html ui stuff for you

Comment: but can i design the GUI of mac application by using the way of HTML,CSS,JavaScript, is this possible? i means similar way

Answer (score 2):

You can add GUI controls programmatically in iphone sdk. but for that you need to know Objective C. If you know objective c the you can create a Label, Button, textfield etc.

For creating a Label

```
UILabel *label = [[UIlabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xAxis_position,yAxis_position,Width,Height)];
```

Set a text

```
label.text = @"Sample";
```

then add it to the view.

```
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

A .xib (UI File) file is a kind of xml file only. In xCode if you right click on the .xib file and choose to view it as source code then you will see something similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="8.00">
    <data>
        <int key="IBDocument.SystemTarget">1280</int>
        <string key="IBDocument.SystemVersion">10K549</string>
        <string key="IBDocument.InterfaceBuilderVersion">1938</string>
        <string key="IBDocument.AppKitVersion">1038.36</string>
        <string key="IBDocument.HIToolboxVersion">461.00</string>
        <object class="NSMutableDictionary" key="IBDocument.PluginVersions">
            <string key="NS.key.0">com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin</string>
            <string key="NS.object.0">933</string>
        </object>
        <array key="IBDocument.IntegratedClassDependencies">
```